# Did they allow smoking in the USA Courts in 1960s?

Tags: realism, the-trial-of-the-chicago-7

This is the scene from *The Trial of the Chicago 7 (2020)*:

[image]

Did they allow smoking in the USA Courts?

Comment: People smoked in public buildings and inside their office until maybe 20 years ago. Just saying. Stuff changed dramatically in a relatively short time.

Comment: A better question is why is only 1 person smoking? It should have been at least 5 or 6 out of the dozen in that shot. But, as this Q shows, that may have been too distracting. Plus they're probably using it to highlight that 1 individual

Comment: Was there anywhere smoking *wasn't* allowed in the 1960s? As mentioned in another comment, the only thing unrealistic in this scene is that many more people should be smoking.

Comment: In WW2 and Korea, (US at least) soldiers were _issued_ cigarettes because they were thought to be beneficial. The Surgeon General's report, most people's first clue they were bad, was in 1964, and it took some time for people to modify their (addicted) behavior.

Comment: @JörgWMittag inside armouries, surgical operating theaters, service station forecourt, during satellite assembly, in a gunpowder factory or grain/flour silo.   Socially, I don't remember ever seeing anyone smoking in a funeral or church either.

Comment: We didn't even ban smoking on *planes* fully until 2000 in the US.

Comment: In 197x a guest in our house was shocked that we did not provide them an ashtray.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Now?  No.  Back then?  Most likely.  I am old enough to have had a job where we could smoke at our desk.  Smoking was just a part of life, it was allowed on airplanes even.  So, while I can't say for certain if it was allowed in courthouses, I can say based on my personal recollections that it most likely was in 1968 (when the events in the movie took place).

Comment: I've been on planes in the last decade that still have ashtrays built into the armrests, even though smoking has been banned on all flights for as long as I can remember.

Comment: IIRC airplanes had designated non-smoking areas.

Comment: -1 Sorry, "most likely was in 1968" isn't really an answer. I'd like to see a citation/reference.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman: I don't know about arm rests, but the FAA specifically requires an ashtray in the lavatory (so that when the flight attendant begins knocking on the door after you set off the smoke alarm, you (hopefully) don't panic and flush the cigarette down the toilet or something).

Comment: @Barmar: (wikipedia says) nosmoking zones in airplanes started in 1971. Even in the 1980s they weren't universal, because on some trips I wasn't able to sit in one.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 I was 10 years old in 1971, I may never have flown before then.

Comment: @barmar - While planes may have had no smoking sections, enforcement was lax at best. I once had someone sitting next to me dump his beer on me because I asked him to stop smoking in the no-smoking section. And then the stewardess accused *me* of being a trouble-maker.

Comment: @camden_kid - you don't need citations for things still in living memory. You just need people who were there at the time.

Comment: @Tetsujin There's nothing in living memory from this answer either - "I can't say for certain if it was allowed in courthouses, I can say based on my personal recollections that _it most likely_ was in 1968". Nothing definite about that statement.

Comment: @camden_kid You’re just making it sound like a kid questioning the recollection of his grandparents. You don’t need to have been in any particular place at that time to know that it’s very likely true, you really just need to have lived through those times.

Comment: The Smoke Free Illinois Act took effect in 2008 (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoke_Free_Illinois_Act#:~:text=The%20Smoke%20Free%20Illinois%20Act,government%20or%20other%20public%20body.). That's 60 years after the events of the movie. Given the prevalence of public smoking at the time and the fact that legislation banning smoking in government buildings was six decades away, I'd say "most likely" is a good call.

Comment: @Tetsujin Nope. I just want proof that folk were was allowed to smoke in USA courts in the 1960s. It's quite simple really. If some asked me the same about UK courts in the 1970s I might say _it was likely_ because I was around in those days but I can't **say for certain**.

Comment: I remember taking my first flight in 1983 and, when offered the choice, I chose a non-smoking seat, thinking I'd have a smoke-free experience. As it turned out, they put me in the first row behind the smoking section so I might as well have been IN the smoking section. There was no partition or barrier between the smoking and non-smoking areas.

Comment: @camden_kid By default, everything is allowed *unless* there's a law against it, or a law giving someone authority to make the restriction (such as the judge of a court).  So, by default, smoking was allowed in court rooms unless there was a law against it, or a judge banned it in his court for some reason.  In other words, smoking was "allowed" simply because it was not banned. No further proof is needed.

Comment: @camden_kid What kind of evidence would be helpful to you?  A photo?  How would you know when it was taken, or whether it was staged?  A news article?  Why would a news article bother reporting on people smoking in a courtroom if it was an everyday occurrence?

Answer (score 37):

Given that you could smoke even in hospitals at around that time, this is an accurate depiction of courts of the era:

> In the 1960s and even into the 1970s and ‘80s smoking was permitted nearly everywhere: smokers could light up at work, in hospitals, in school buildings, in bars, in restaurants, and even on buses, trains and planes
>
> [The Changing Public Image of Smoking in the United States: 1964–2014](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3894634/)

The laws have gradually changed since then, from allowing smoking everywhere to allowing it only in designated spaces to not allowing it anywhere indoors in public places, but this hasn’t always been enforced. Even [as late as 1989](https://www.sun-sentinel.com/news/fl-xpm-1989-03-24-8901160280-story.html) ([alt link](https://archive.is/kknsz)), one Florida courthouse had a haze of smoke in its hallways from all the smoking done inside it, against the rules.

Comment: The latter link isn't accessible from the EU.

Comment: @Polygnome Does this work for you? https://archive.is/kknsz

Comment: Also high schools. My older brother's high school had a smoking area for the students to use in the late 1970s.

Comment: This is a better answer than the accepted answer, because (1) it cites evidence, and (2) the evidence is about courthouses in particular.

Answer (score 11):

As far as I recall, the mere idea of "can't smoke in here" didn't exist in the 1960s.

There were "No Smoking" zones, but for reasons.

I remember smokers in hospitals (including patients), airplanes (later, the back N rows), at the community pool, at the dinner table, everywhere.

Comment: In 1960, the only place you *couldn't* smoke was a gas station.

Comment: @Mazura You could smoke at a gas station, As I recall, the signs only said not to do it when you were pumping gas. Because when you got out of your car, you were holding the cigarette you were smoking while you drove up.

Comment: @OwenReynolds - The signs I remember were just "No Smoking," full stop. Separately there were signs warning that smoking during pumping could end badly for you (I paraphrase), but the big bold sign was a blanket prohibition.

Comment: One other exception was the computer room. In those days the computer (rarely more than one) was large, expensive, and delicate, and got its own special air-conditioning with particle filtering, while people often didn't.

Comment: I still see people smoking at gas stations while pumping gas in 2020.

Comment: @jesse_b Although that gene or meme pool is shrinking.

Answer (score 0):

The Chicago 7 were [tried in the U.S. District Court for the Northern District of Illinois](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicago_Seven#Grand_jury_and_indictment), a federal court, in **1969**.

In **1972** the US Surgeon General proposed limits on smoking areas, but it wasn't until **1997** that President Clinton [banned smoking in federal buildings via Executive Order 13058](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2724464/).

I worked in federal government buildings in the mid-90s and smoking was already not allowed indoors, though I'm not sure by what mandate. Society had changed by then and it was no longer considered acceptable to smoke in a crowded building even if there were no explicit rules prohibiting it.